# Raising process integrity without UAC prompt

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, windows-10

The objective is to prevent local user accounts from killing my process. AFAIK, that is achieved by either executing the process as an administrator or by raising the process's integrity.

Currently, I'm using the .exe's manifest file to execute the process with administrator privileges. My user is of type administrator and simply has to click on "yes" to the UAC prompt. I would like to be free of that hassle and raise my process's integrity programmatically. But in the following excerpt, `SetTokenInformation()` has error "A required privilege is not held by the client". I enabled all privileges using [UserRights.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0) but it still shows the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void failure(const char *message, const int line)
{
    char buf[256] = { 0 };
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&buf, sizeof(buf), NULL);

    puts(buf);

    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken) == 0)
        failure("OpenProcessToken()", __LINE__);

    ULONG cbSid = GetSidLengthRequired(1);
    TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = { { alloca(cbSid) } };

    if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinHighLabelSid, NULL, tml.Label.Sid, &cbSid) == 0)
        failure("CreateWellKnownSid()", __LINE__);

    if (SetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(tml)) == 0)
        failure("SetTokenInformation()", __LINE__);

    CloseHandle(hToken);

    getchar();

return 0;
}
```

```
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeNetworkLogonRight
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeTcbPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeMachineAccountPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeInteractiveLogonRight
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeBackupPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeSystemtimePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeTimeZonePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeCreatePagefilePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeCreateTokenPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeCreatePermanentPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeDebugPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeEnableDelegationPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeAuditPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeImpersonatePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeLoadDriverPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeLockMemoryPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeBatchLogonRight
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeServiceLogonRight
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeSecurityPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeRelabelPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeManageVolumePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeSystemProfilePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeUndockPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeRestorePrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeShutdownPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeSyncAgentPrivilege
Grant-UserRight DESKTOP-xxxxxxx\myusername SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
```

Comment: you can not set `TokenIntegrityLevel` higher than current in token. set lower - can.

Comment: really if want be more exactly, you need have `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` (*SeTcbPrivilege*) for do this - up `TokenIntegrityLevel` in token. but you have not this privilege. but if you even have it - you will got another error in this code - `C000012B` - *An attempt was made to establish a token for use as a primary token but the token is already in use. A token can only be the primary token of one process at a time.*, for avoid it we can for example add line `DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT, 0, ::SecurityImpersonation, ::TokenPrimary, &hNewToken);`

Comment: with this set `TokenIntegrityLevel` will be work ok (side note you need only `TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT` instead `TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS`. but one problem - `hNewToken` already not related to your process :)

Comment: To avoid UAC prompt every time, you can let a service launch your process elevated, e. g. Windows task scheduler. Of course, to register your process with task scheduler, you need to elevate once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find this behaviour is by design.  If any process could silently run elevated at the drop of a hat, what security would there be?

Addendum: Microsoft know how to do this, but it is reserved for things like the Settings app or Disk Management in MMC.  The on-screen keyboard (OSK) is another one.  This runs elevated without ever prompting the user.  One rule for them, one rule for us, eh?

Comment: this is (like *osk.exe*) auto-elevated processes. it names/locations hard-coded. even in early versions of win 10 was possibility abuse this and launch self process in place it. but in latest builds this is fixed, possible no more hole  here

Comment: @RbMm Really?  That's horrible.